# Redirect to full URL with htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to load images from production website if they don't exist on my local environment, for that, I have this htaccess rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule uploads/(.*)$ http://www.productionserver.com/uploads/$1 [R=302,L,NC]
```

The problem:

### Original URL:

http://localhost:8080/myproject/uploads/image.jpg

### Output:

http://localhost:8080/myproject/http://www.productionserver.com/uploads/image.jpg

### Desired output:

http://www.productionserver.com/uploads/image.jpg

What must I change in order to achieve that?

Comment: I'm sure this has been answered already, but I've been looking for a solution for 30 minutes and still haven't found one.

Comment: Your rule is fine. Test in a different browser.

Comment: Tested this in a docker container and it worked fine for me with your code as pasted.

Comment: I moved the code to the top of the .htaccess file and it worked fine. It seems some other rule was interfering with it. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Just for your info, I got the "Output" mentioned in the question by using a tool. Now I'm not sure if that output is correct. The tool I used: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be

Answer (score 0):

The code was correct.

I moved it to the top of my .htaccess file and it worked. Some other rule was interfering with it.

I believe the tool I was using to debug the "Output" was wrong. The tool is: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be

Thanks everyone who replied on the comments.